# Metronome app for Android that can increase speed after a specified number of bars

Tags: android, music

I'm looking for an Android metronome app with the usual features:

- choose the speed
- choose how many beats (3/4, 4/4, etc)
- choose to play quarters, octaves, 16th, triplets, etc

Plus:

- choose a number of bars after which the speed increases of some quantity, and then again until it reaches a fixed speed.

Free is better, but for a good product I can spend a couple of euros.

**Note**:  I know very well that there are [dozens of metronome apps in the Play store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=metronome&c=apps). I tried some without finding the feature I want. So I came here hoping someone knew the right app.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Pro Metronome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eumlab.android.prometronome) as well? It looks quite powerful and allows you to:

- choose speed,
- change beats,
- select and change accents and subdivisions,
- from what I've seen, vary the tempo after a certain amount of time and return to the initial setup (in the warmup mode, and you need to precise it yourself).

Maybe worth a look.